# How to get coordinates from array?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have an array with some coords

```
coords = [];
```

`console.log(coords);` gives me

```
  []
    0: "45.461,9.177"
    1: "40.85150386578784,14.258907499999964"
    2: "45.46135436613811,9.175124650000043"
```

Now I need to draw the markers based on these coords, and place the lat and lng in 2 different input fields, so I do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
  console.log(coords[i]);
  var circle = new L.CircleMarker([coords[i]]);
  circles.addLayer(circle);
  circle.on('click', function (e) {
    var curPos = e.target.getLatLng();
    $("#longiTude").val(curPos.lat);
    $("#latiTude").val(curPos.lng);
    submitSearchForm();
  });
}
```

But that gives me the following error

> Projection.SphericalMercator.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'lat' of null

If I do console.log(circle); it gives me

```
NewClass {options: {…}, _latlng: null, _radius: 10, _initHooksCalled: true}
options:
__proto__: Object
_events:
click: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
_initHooksCalled: true
_latlng: null
_radius: 10
__proto__: NewClass
```

Which looks like it is not reading the coords in the array `var circle = new L.CircleMarker([coords[i]]);`

I tried to do `var circle = new L.CircleMarker(coords[i]);` without `[]` but same error occurs

Comment: What does `L.CircleMarker` expect as arguments? It looks like you are passing is a string inside an array like like `["45.461,9.177"]`

Comment: @MarkMeyer it expects an array, thought I was passing an array tho, see updated question at the bottom

Comment: @MarkMeyer bingo! Thanks a lot. if you place that into an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coords` contains strings like:

`"45.461,9.177"`

but it looks like `L.CircleMarker` is expecting an array. You can split the strings on the comma to give `CircleMarker` an array of values with:

```
 L.CircleMarker(coords[i].split(','))
```